# nice css holder without image

Tags: html, css

any technique that can be used to place on image-holder while waiting for image to load. a typical way of doing is placing dummy image while waiting for real image to load.

my image code like below

```
<div id="realimage" style="background-image: real_image.jpg"/>
```

1. any nice way to put as image holder without putting dummy image? using pure css without javascript possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as the source of the dummy image. It will load with the HTML and will not require an additional request.

So, in your CSS you could do this (embedding a red dot):

```
.realimage {background: url('data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD/
//+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4U
g9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')}
```

This is not supported on IE 6/7 and in IE 8 there is a 32k limit on the size of the image.

Comment: I don't think this will answer the question, because he's already using `background-image` for the *real* image. Also, my brain, upon seeing this, is going "images don't belong in CSS files! They just don't!" Best answer given the circumstance though

Comment: @Yi Jiang - I know where you are coming from. Data URIs can also be placed directly in the `<img src="" />` tag, if that's any comfort.

Comment: @Oded , the dummy image that you suggested. how do i use pure css to replace the realimage in the 'div' ?

Comment: @cometta - What I had posted _is_ pure CSS

Comment: @Oded anyway to do when the page first loaded, dummy image is used, when real image is ready, it replace the dummy image?

Comment: @cometta - you will have to use javascript for that, replacing the page src and clearing out the background url from the style.

Answer (score 0):

in css3 you can add multiple background images:

```
.realimage {
  background-image: url(haevy.png), url(dummy.png);
  background-position: center, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The first image is the top image

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MbpgL/1/

warning: older browsers versions don't always like CSS3 especially IE. But i say people who do not upgrade/date don't deserve nice websites!